# Apply divinff to discontinuous data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a set of position measurements that I have to pass through a linear regression in order to obtain slope value.

I do some subsetting first and I get this data frame (showing subset).

```
   us[1:30,1:5]
     estado Tiempo    UT    TR UT.CHX
3087      3  618.2 16561 15861  16313
3088      3  618.4 16561 15861  16313
3089      3  618.6 16561 15861  16313
3090      3  618.8 16561 15861  16313
3091      3  619.0 16561 15861  16313
3092      3  619.2 16561 15861  16313
3093      3  619.4 16561 15861  16313
3094      3  619.6 16561 15861  16313
3095      3  619.8 16561 15861  16313
3096      3  620.0 16561 15861  16313
3097      3  620.2 16561 15861  16313
3098      3  620.4 16561 15861  16313
3099      3  620.6 16561 15861  16313
3100      3  620.8 16561 15861  16313
3101      3  621.0 16561 15861  16313
3102      3  621.2 16561 15861  16313
3103      3  621.4 16561 15861  16313
3104      3  621.6 16561 15861  16313
3105      3  621.8 16561 15860  16313
3106      3  622.0 16561 15860  16313
3107      3  622.2 16561 15860  16313
3108      3  622.4 16561 15859  16313
3109      3  622.6 16561 15859  16313
3110      3  622.8 16561 15859  16313
3111      3  623.0 16561 15859  16313
3112      3  623.2 16561 15859  16312
3113      3  623.4 16561 15859  16310
3114      3  623.6 16561 15859  16309
3115      3  623.8 16561 15859  16308
3116      3  624.0 16561 15859  16307
```

I have to set the first value of each time start to zero (you can see that "Tiempo" column is not continuous, it jumps values in sets of 45 rows) and relativize the next values within each set to that initial position. The idea behind that is to obtain a set of increasing values for each column (as the position varies) and plot that against "Tiempo" variable to get the slope of each column later.

If I use

```
veltraining<-cbind(us$Tiempo,diffinv(abs(diff(as.matrix(us[,3:length(us)])))))
```

The discontinuos jump ruins the job.

```
    veltraining[1:30,1:5]
       col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 [1,] 618.2    0    0    0    0
 [2,] 618.4    0    0    0    0
 [3,] 618.6    0    0    0    0
 [4,] 618.8    0    0    0    0
 [5,] 619.0    0    0    0    0
 [6,] 619.2    0    0    0   10
 [7,] 619.4    0    0    0   19
 [8,] 619.6    0    0    0   25
 [9,] 619.8    0    0    0   33
[10,] 620.0    0    0    0   39
[11,] 620.2    0    0    0   42
[12,] 620.4    0    0    0   42
[13,] 620.6    0    0    0   42
[14,] 620.8    0    0    0   43
[15,] 621.0    0    0    0   44
[16,] 621.2    0    0    0   44
[17,] 621.4    0    0    0   45
[18,] 621.6    0    0    0   47
[19,] 621.8    0    1    0   49
[20,] 622.0    0    1    0   51
[21,] 622.2    0    1    0   53
[22,] 622.4    0    2    0   55
[23,] 622.6    0    2    0   56
[24,] 622.8    0    2    0   58
[25,] 623.0    0    2    0   58
[26,] 623.2    0    2    1   72
[27,] 623.4    0    2    3   80
[28,] 623.6    0    2    4   80
[29,] 623.8    0    2    5   83
[30,] 624.0    0    2    6   92
```

The expected output should be a data frame like this (subset). Don't mind the column names, it's just I named us columns after I did this post, the order is the same.

```
primer[1:10,1:7]
   Tiempo UT TR UT.CHX TR.CHX TR.CHX.1 UT.CHX.1
1   618.2  0  0      0      0        0        0
2   618.4  0  0      0      0        0        0
3   618.6  0  0      0      0        0        0
4   618.8  0  0      0      0        0        0
5   619.0  0  0      0      0        9        0
6   619.2  0  0      0     10       14        0
7   619.4  0  0      0     19       15        0
8   619.6  0  0      0     25       18        0
9   619.8  0  0      0     33       39        0
10  620.0  0  0      0     39       64        0
```

I don't know how to split the data frame simply - meaning without a lot of subsetting, naming and stuff like that - and I don't know if the "diffinv(abs(diff..." strategy is the best.

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you are trying to do - could you possibly explain it in a different way / in more detail? Or maybe just take a very small chunk of your supplied data, say 10 or 15 rows of `us`, and manually create an example of what that small `data.frame` should look like after it has been appropriately transformed?

Comment: @nrussell I put the expected output in my post with the position built from zero and rising. You can notice that the dput veltraining is the same but the whole thing with the position jumps when time jumps.

Comment: I also cannot understand what you are trying to do. The fact that the sample data doesn't match up to the sample results is a quite confusing as well. you really haven't clearly identified where the problem is. Also, the sample `us` values seem unnecessarily large. Minimal, reproducible examples are best.